# Kivy launcher crashes on loading

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, pyserial

Im building an app for android and before I make standalone .apk I want to try it using Kivy Launcher. In my app Im using pyserial module which I installed on android using python-for-android, but kivy launcher still crashes and last log output is "no module named serial". How can I fix this?

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /storage/emulated/0/kivy/CarLockApp/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-09-28_1.txt
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.0
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.2 (default, Apr  2 2015, 13:52:41) 
[GCC 4.8]
[INFO              ] Factory: 173 symbols loaded
[WARNING           ] stderr: /data/data/org.kivy.pygame/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
[WARNING           ] stderr: (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] Text: Provider: pygame
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:     import serial
[WARNING           ] stderr: ImportError: No module named serial
```

Comment: The kivy launcher doesn't have pyserial. How did you try to install it?

Comment: I tried to install it through python-for-android and qpython apps

Comment: python-for-android builds android apks. Did you try to build a kivy launcher apk with it? And qpython is not relevant, it has its own python installation.

Comment: How can i build apk through python-for-android?

Comment: By following the instructions. If you have a problem with them, raise it.

Comment: Ok, but can you tell me how can I add pyserial module to Kivy Launcher?